# Flask - Output to return only fields selected from a web page

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I have got a Flask website that has a list of fields from which the user can select.

```
@app.route('/sample', methods=['GET','POST'])
def sample_template():
    form = TemplateForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        student_id = form.student_id.data
        class_id = form.class_id.data
        age_id = form.age_id.data
        status_id = form.status_id.data

        output = sample_function(student_id, class_id, age_id, status_id)
```

Since each of the above mentioned fields are check boxes, the user can select any of the fields (either all of them or selected list). I am trying to modify the line where it tries to generate the **output**.

```
output = sample_function(student_id, class_id, age_id, status_id)
```

Instead of having the columns fixed how could I make them dynamic such that depending on the fields selected only those fields should be returned in the output.

For example if only student_id, class_id are selected then the funtion should be

```
output = sample_function(student_id, class_id)
```

Thanks

Query that gets executed:

```
cursor.execute('select {} from sales.format(', '.join(str(field) for field in field_names)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop over the fields, add them to a dictionary and use that dictionary as kwargs for the `carrier_sample` function. However, your field names should have the same name as the arguments for the `carrier_sample` function.

e.g.:

```
def sample_function(student_id=None, class_id=None, age_id=None, status_id=None):
    # do logic here
    pass

if form.validate_on_submit():
    kwargs = {}
    for field_name in ['student_id', 'class_id', 'age_id', 'status_id']:
        field = getattr(form, field_name)
        if field.data:
            kwargs[field_name] = field.data
    sample_function(**kwargs)
```

However, I'm not sure if this would be the most elegant solution for your problem or if you should change the design of the piece of logic.

Comment: just wondering if I should be changing the sql that gets executed when this function runs. I have pasted the SQL that I am currently trying to execute. Could you please assist. Thanks..